# How to transform any data into symmetrized dot patterns (SDP) using Python?

Tags: python

A lot of scientific research exists on transforming data into Symmetrized Dot Patterns (SDP) which is a flower-pedals-like pattern that is mapped in polar space instead of triangular space. The equations for implementing SDP are quite simple and 3 of them are needed for the transformation. I attached a picture of the equations to give you an idea. I also attached pictures of how the signal looks before and after transformation which is the result I am hoping to achieve using my own data. Both pictures are screenshots from the paper mentioned at the top of one of the pictures. Does anyone have any insight on how to practically implement this in python? Any help is greatly appreciated, Thank you all for taking the time to read my question!

What I tried so far is to implement the first equation like this:

for i in k3:

```
rofi=((i-minofk)/(maxofk-minofk))

print(rofi)
```

and I got the result. But I want is the actual graph and I am not sure about how to implement all equations and actually arrive at a final result like in the attached picture.

Thanks again!
[Transformation example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkfRC.png)

[equations explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvcXA.png)

Comment: Don't have time to get into the details of figuring this out, but I remembered [this polar plotting](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_scatter.html) from matplotlib python package

Comment: Thank you! I’m still trying to figure it out.